# How to align using bootstrap?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap on a site I made for practical purposes, but the names of some books are too long and I can't align them? How can I align these books? I need help.

```
@model BookListModel

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var books in Model.results)
        {
         
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="@books.formats.imagejpeg" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">@books.title</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
            }
        </div>
</div>
```

[Page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yVC5.png)

I created the objects as Card, but I am getting the same error there.

Comment: If using bootstrap 5, use ```text-truncate```. It should also be available in bootstrap 4 as well. Please try searching docs for once https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/text-truncation/

Comment: @Binit Yes it worked, but there is something missing, how can I fix it. Book titles were shortened straight away, for example A Modest Proposal: For Preventing The C like that

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I'd fix that. I don't have much experience in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

to center text add "text-center" class to the parent element same you can type the code for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).